# Synthesize musical notes (with piano sounds) in Python

Tags: python, audio, midi

I would like to have a python implementation of a musical instrument library (for instance, a piano object) that I can use to convert a list of notes and a duration into sound.  For instance, something like:

```
import Piano

pn = Piano()
pn.play([note, note, ..., note], duration)
```

Does something like this exist for python 2.7? I would like to implement it if it doesn't. I currently have something that uses audiere, but its just sine waves so it sounds horrible. Is there any way to hook into a midi piano or something like that- I am using windows 7? Are there any implementing steps that I might not expect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to synthesize sounds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790960/how-to-synthesize-sounds)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A subset of @Marcelos answer: http://code.google.com/p/mingus/

> mingus is a package for Python used by programmers, musicians, composers and researchers to make and investigate music. **At the core of mingus is music theory, which includes topics like intervals, chords, scales and progressions**.
>
> The MIDI package can save and load MIDI files, and -last but not least- provides a general purpose sequencer for all the containers and a FluidSynth sequencer subclass. **This allows you to play all your data structures straight from Python in just a couple of lines**. Most of the icky timing and MIDI code has been abstracted away for you, leaving a clean, relatively simple API.

Comment: Thank you, that does indeed answer the question. For interested parties, I ended up building what I wanted with [midiutil](http://code.google.com/p/midiutil/)

Answer (score 23):

A student of mine has just started using mingus to do just this so here's quick guide on how to get going on linux (ubuntu):

Install fluidsynth and mingus if you don't have them already:

`$` sudo apt-get install fluidsynth

`$` sudo easy_install mingus

Now you should be able to open python and type:

```
>>> from mingus.midi import fluidsynth   
>>> fluidsynth.init('/usr/share/sounds/sf2/FluidR3_GM.sf2',"alsa")
```

This imports the necessary stuff from mingus and initialises fluidsynth to play through alsa  (not jack which is the default). Then:

```
>>> fluidsynth.play_Note(64,0,100)
```

...and you should hear a note played on the piano (arguments are: note number, channel number and velocity).

For more information go here:

https://code.google.com/p/mingus/wiki/tutorialFluidsynth

Comment: for ubuntu, I used "pip install mingus". Do not use python3/pip3, seems not to work.