# Music21 Midi Error: type object '_io.StringIO' has no attribute 'StringIO'. How to fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, music21

So, I've followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983462/how-can-i-produce-real-time-audio-output-from-music-made-with-music21) in order to get some sound playing with [Music21](http://web.mit.edu/music21/), and here's the code:

```
from music21 import *
import random

def main():

#  Set up a detuned piano 
#  (where each key has a random 
#  but consistent detuning from 30 cents flat to sharp)
#  and play a Bach Chorale on it in real time.


    keyDetune = []
    for i in range(0, 127):
        keyDetune.append(random.randint(-30, 30))

    b = corpus.parse('bach/bwv66.6')
    for n in b.flat.notes:
        n.microtone = keyDetune[n.midi]
    sp = midi.realtime.StreamPlayer(b)
    sp.play()

    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

And here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 49, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 44, in main
    sp.play()
  File "G:\Development\Python Development\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\music21\mi
di\realtime.py", line 104, in play
    streamStringIOFile = self.getStringIOFile()
  File "G:\Development\Python Development\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\music21\mi
di\realtime.py", line 110, in getStringIOFile
    return stringIOModule.StringIO(streamMidiWritten)
AttributeError: type object '_io.StringIO' has no attribute 'StringIO'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I'm running Python 3.4 x86 (Anaconda Distribution) on Windows 7 x64. I have no idea on how to fix this (But probably is some obscure Python 2.x to Python 3.x incompatibility issue, *as always*)

EDIT:

I've edited the import as suggested in the answer, and now I got a TypeError:

[image]

What would you recommend me to do as an alternative to "play some audio" with Music21? (Fluidsynth or whatever, anything).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may be right... I *think* the error may actually be in Music21, with the way it handles importing `StringIO`

Python 2 has `StringIO.StringIO`, whereas

Python 3 has `io.StringIO`

..but if you look at the import statement in `music21\midi\realtime.py`

```
try:
    import cStringIO as stringIOModule
except ImportError:
    try:
        import StringIO as stringIOModule
    except ImportError:
        from io import StringIO as stringIOModule
```

The last line is importing `io.StringIO`, and so later on the call to `stringIOModule.StringIO()` fails because it's actually calling `io.StringIO.StringIO`.

I would try to edit the import statement to:

```
    except ImportError:
        import io as stringIOModule
```

And see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thank you very much SiHa. Your suggestion worked, but I got a TypeError afterwards (I've edited the question and included a screenshot).

Comment: Hmm. Not sure, sorry. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914472/stringio-in-python3) question mentions the String / Byte thing w.r.t. Python2 / 3 though. To me it looks like this hasn't been properly tested with Python3.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I think as well.

Comment: I think I've fixed this now.  Thanks! I am having a heck of a time testing since I've never been able to get pygame to work with Python 3 properly on the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

return stringIOModule.StringIO(streamMidiWritten)
AttributeError: type object '_io.StringIO' has no attribute 'StringIO'
Press any key to continue . . .

Please @Ericsson, just remove the StringIO from the return value and you are good to go.

It will now be:
 return stringIOModule(streamMidiWritten)